# Web API call OK from Chrome, Fail from IE9 (DotNetNuke)

Tags: ajax, web-services, dotnetnuke, asp.net-web-api

I am baffled by this one. I am writing a Web API method that when called via ajax in Chrome works fine but the same call returns "Unauthorized" when make in IE9... I am using DotNetNuke 7's implementation of Web API and in debug the call does not hit my breakpoint in the method "processUpload". What might be causing this?

Here are my snippets, thanks for the help

```
data = { alc: 'private', bucket: 'Dev', file: file.name, key: 'drop/' };
$.ajax({
    url: sf.getServiceRoot('mySite') + "Upload/processUpload",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders
}).done(function (response, status) {
    if (status == "success") {
        params[response.file] = { policy: response.policy, signature: response.signature }
    }
}).fail(function (xhr, result, status) {
    alert("Uh-oh, something broke: " + status);
});
```

Comment: Are you perhaps logged in with one browser, and not in the other?

Answer (score 0):

This is what my ajax call looks like

```
odata = { alc: 'private', bucket: 'Dev', file: file.name, key: 'drop/' };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: sf.getServiceRoot('mySite') + "Upload/processUpload",
        beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
        data: odata ,
        success: function (result) {
            params[response.file] = { policy: response.policy, signature: response.signature }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert("Uh-oh, something broke: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

What you could also try is modifying your web.config as below

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```